# SyncFramwork And SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using SyncFramework  I have one table. In that I have to sync some columns up and some columns down and some columns up and down.....

How can I  do this in a single schema for client and server....dbs...

Is there any chance... if not possible please tell me how to write different schemas... for each...side and each direction....

The following are columns in my table:

```
**Column            Direction**
AddressID        x  both
AddressIDpda        
AccountID        x  down
Line1            x  down
Line2            x  down
Line3            x  both
Line4            x  both
ApartmentNumber  x  down
City             x  down
StateOrProvince  x  down
PostalCode       x  down
ObjectID         x  down
ObjectType       x  down
CreatedOn        x  Both
ModifiedOn       x  both
MoveToCRM        x  both
twg_PDAupdated   x  up
twg_PDAcreated   x  up
twg_User         x  up
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest you can do this is to define 3 scopes with different objectprefix or schema. you will however end up with multiple sync objects (e.g., 9 triggers, 24 insert/update/delete stored procs, 3 select changes stored procs, etc...)

or you can hack your way into the scope config table so that sync framework calls your custom stored procs for inserting/updating columns differently.

Comment: According to your suggestion I have created 2 scopes and both have different SyncDirectionOrder. scope one contains columns AddressID,AccountID,,AddressIDpda,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,MoveToCRM,twg_User and scope 2nd contains columns AddressID,AccountID,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4, ApartmentNumber and etc.. when I try to sync both at a time I am geting error message "The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = base,Column name = Line1 ]" plz helpe me to solve this problem

Comment: have you created them under a different schema or object prefix?

Comment: I have create diffrent schema for each. object prefix I don't know how to create.

Comment: ObjectPrefix and ObjectSchema are properties of SqlSyncScopeProvisioning. look them up in the documentation.